# Installed gnome and now desktop is empty

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I recently installed gnome using:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Now I rebooted my system and it all looked fine however the desktop remains empty, I can paste symbols onto my desktop and this results in my desktop receiving a copy of my symbol, suggesting that it's not a folder related issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does it mean _my desktop receiving a copy of my symbol_?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GNOME desktop environment hides desktop icons by default.  If you want them to display open the GNOME `tweak-tool` under the `Desktop` tab set `Icons on Desktop` to `ON`.

[image: Gnome Tweak Tool Desktop settings]

If you do not have the GNOME `tweak-tool` you can install it using the command `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`or search for it in the Ubuntu Software Center.